# How do we run a single test using Google bazel

Tags: c++, bazel

For running all the tests under a target I use the command line command

```
bazel test //src/code_path:target_name
```

What should be additional parameters to run a test `single_test` from the above target?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On Googletest with the following setup:

```
TEST(TestSuite, test1)
TEST(TestSuite, test2)
```

you can isolate test1 using

```
bazel test --test_arg=--gtest_filter=TestSuite.test $TEST_TARGET_PATH
```

See [--gtest_filter](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md#running-a-subset-of-the-tests)

Comment: should that be `--test_arg=--gtest_filter=TestSuite.test1`?

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to use [`--test_filter`](https://bazel.build/reference/command-line-reference#flag--test_filter).

The specific format of the value to the flag depends on the test runner.

Comment: An example would help a lot.

Comment: The value to use with the flag depends on the test runner. So without more information, there's no example to give.

Answer (score 4):

[--test_filter](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/user-manual.html#flag--test_filter) can be used:

For the following googletest test:

```
TEST(glog, log) {
  LOG(INFO) << "an INFO log message";
  VLOG(1) << "a vlog(1) message";
}
```

`--test_filter=glog.log` can be used to pick it.

Answer (score 2):

To give a specific example for the default C++ testrunner (not the general "depends on which test runner you use"):

For a test:

```
TEST_F(HiMomFixture, testCall)
{
  EXPECT_EQ(..)
}
```

Select this with:

```
bazel test ... --test_filter HiMom*
or
bazel test ... --test_filter Hi*
```

Reference: [ahumesky answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60233815)

Answer (score 0):

```
bazel test --test_output=streamed --test_filter='single_test' //src/code_path:target_name
```